# DateTimePicker updates the value a bit too early

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I'm using a DateTimePicker (.net).

Is there a way to update the value only when the calendar closes?
Or is there a way to know when the calendar open/closes?

The DateTimePicker is bound to an object and this object check the dates and pop a message box when needed. When the user is browsing for a date, the message box appears. I only want this rule to execute when the date is chosen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a CloseUp event.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do something with this event.